# Error: nativeNC failed:

Tags: javascript, node.js, meteor

I have uploaded a Meteor application to a production environment. I am getting the following error:

> ... Error: nativeNC failed:
>
> at sendMessage
>   (/bundle/programs/server/npm/node_modules/sync-rpc/lib/index.js:121:13)
>   at
>   /bundle/programs/server/npm/node_modules/sync-rpc/lib/index.js:154:25
>   at request
>   (/bundle/programs/server/npm/node_modules/sync-request/lib/index.js:28:15)

I don't have any idea about the reason why this happens.

Comment: Define "production". Was it working on your local environment? If yes, what about intermediate ones, like Staging? What about another computer? Have you set a dependency by mistake to a devDependency in your package.json? I would start by trying to answer these questions.

Comment: Yes it was working on my local host. Production means some hosting provider. I had a gamble for the reason which apparently was true and that the reason is the failure is caused by insufficient resources. So after up-scaling the application it worked